# How to avoid consecutive nested .Any in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm having a Collection List BossList. In that I'm using nested .Any() to determine the condition. Now the Performance is Very slow in my real project. Consider the following sample source code.

```
void Main()
{

    List<Boss> BossList = new List<Boss>()
    {
        new Boss()
        {
            ID = 101,
            Name = "Harry",
            Department = "Development",
            Gender = "Male",
            Role = "Manager",
            Employees = new List<Person>() {
                new Person() {
                    ID = 101, 
                    SID = 102, 
                    Name = "Peter", 
                    Department = "Development", 
                    Gender = "Male", 
                    Role = "Assistant",
                    PayInfo = new List<PayrollInfo>()
                    {
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 1, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 6 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 2, NetWorkingDays = 23, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 3, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 2 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 4, NetWorkingDays = 22, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 5, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 6, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 6 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 7, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 8, NetWorkingDays = 21, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 9, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 8 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 10, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 9 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 11, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 12, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 1 },
                    }
                },
                new Person() {
                    ID = 101, 
                    SID = 103, 
                    Name = "Emma Watson", 
                    Department = "Development", 
                    Gender = "Female", 
                    Role = "Assistant",
                    PayInfo = new List<PayrollInfo>() {
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 1, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 5 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 2, NetWorkingDays = 23, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 3, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 4, NetWorkingDays = 22, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 5, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 6, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 9 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 7, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 8, NetWorkingDays = 21, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 9, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 10, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 2 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 11, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 12, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 1 },
                    }
                },

            }
        },
        new Boss()
        {
            ID = 104,
            Name = "Raj",
            Department = "Development",
            Gender = "Male",
            Role = "Manager",
            Employees = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() {
                    ID = 104, 
                    SID = 105, 
                    Name = "Kaliya", 
                    Department = "Development", 
                    Gender = "Male", 
                    Role = "Assistant",
                    PayInfo = new List<PayrollInfo>() {
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 1, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 6 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 2, NetWorkingDays = 23, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 3, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 2 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 4, NetWorkingDays = 22, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 5, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 6, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 6 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 7, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 8, NetWorkingDays = 21, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 9, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 8 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 10, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 9 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 11, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 12, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 1 },
                    }
                },
                new Person() {
                    ID = 104, 
                    SID = 103, 
                    Name = "Emma Watson", 
                    Department = "Development", 
                    Gender = "Female", 
                    Role = "Assistant",
                    PayInfo = new List<PayrollInfo>() {
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 1, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 5 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 2, NetWorkingDays = 23, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 3, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 4, NetWorkingDays = 22, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 5, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 6, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 9 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 7, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 8, NetWorkingDays = 21, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 9, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 10, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 2 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 11, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 12, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 1 },
                    }
                },

            },
        },
        new Boss()
        {
            ID = 102,
            Name = "Peter",
            Department = "Development",
            Gender = "Male",
            Role = "Manager",
            Employees = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() {
                    ID = 102, 
                    SID = 105, 
                    Name = "Kaliya", 
                    Department = "Development", 
                    Gender = "Male", 
                    Role = "Assistant",
                    PayInfo = new List<PayrollInfo>() {
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 1, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 6 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 2, NetWorkingDays = 23, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 3, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 2 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 4, NetWorkingDays = 22, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 5, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 6, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 6 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 7, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 8, NetWorkingDays = 21, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 9, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 8 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 10, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 9 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 11, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 12, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 1 },
                    }
                },
                new Person() {
                    ID = 102, 
                    SID = 103, 
                    Name = "Emma Watson", 
                    Department = "Development", 
                    Gender = "Female", 
                    Role = "Assistant",
                    PayInfo = new List<PayrollInfo>() {
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 1, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 5 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 2, NetWorkingDays = 23, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 3, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 4, NetWorkingDays = 22, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 5, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 6, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 9 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 7, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 4 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 8, NetWorkingDays = 21, AbsentDays = 3 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 9, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 10, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 2 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 11, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 1 },
                        new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 12, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 1 },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    BossList.Where(i => i.Employees.Any(j => j.PayInfo.Any(s => s.AbsentDays >6))).Select(m => m.Name).Dump();
}
```

The Model Classes are

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public List<PayrollInfo> PayInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Boss
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class PayrollInfo
{
    public int Monthof2015 { get; set; }
    public int NetWorkingDays { get; set; }
    public int AbsentDays { get; set; }
}
```

The Main LINQ Query is

```
BossList.Where(i => i.Employees
                      .Any(j => j.PayInfo
                                 .Any(s => s.AbsentDays >6)))
        .Select(m => m.Name);
```

In my main Project, it contains 6 nested .Any(). Here I can't able to create because of lengthy code.

I'm using the query in EF as a IQueryable. The Database contains more than 1000K Records.

Kindly suggest me, is there is any efficient way to maximize the performance ?

Comment: Thanks for the LINQPad code!  Is this a simplified version of a EF query?

Comment: @stuartd - I'm using the query in EF as a IQueryable.

Comment: @IvanStoev - I added it in Question.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way to do this is still using `BossList` as starting point, but build a list of Ids in which their Ids should occur:

```
db.BossList.Where(b => db.PayrollInfos.Where(s => s.AbsentDays >6)
                                .Select(p => p.Employee.BossId)
                   .Contains(b.BossId));
```

In SQL this will probably translate into a neat and efficient `EXISTS` query.

Note that I assume that in your real-life model you have back references (`PayrollInfos.Employee`) and that I used a placeholder `BossId` that you should substitute by the real key properties. From your example it's a bit unclear how the references `ID` and `SID` work.

`db` is your `DbContext` instance.

To explain this approach a bit more: in my experience it usually works best to start a query with the collection that contains the results you're after, i.e. `Bosslist`, and then to add predicates that filter the results. Other answers start with `PayrollInfo`. That's OK, but in the end you need grouping or `Distinct` to remove duplicates. Usually this doesn't make the query plan better than a relatively simple `table WHERE EXSIST( subqyery )`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it please.

Comment: I'm new in this LINQ. Please brief your code please especially PayrollInfos

Comment: I added some clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a watered down EF query; I would reverse your select to start with PayrollInfo and then select the Boss name:

```
Boss Boss = new Boss
{
    ID = 101,
    Name = "Harry",
    Department = "Development",
    Gender = "Male",
    Role = "Manager",
};
Person Person = new Person() { ID = 101, SID = 102, Name = "Peter", Department = "Development", Gender = "Male", Role = "Assistant", Boss = Boss};
List<PayrollInfo> PayrollInfoList = new List<UserQuery.PayrollInfo>
{
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 1, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 6, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 2, NetWorkingDays = 23, AbsentDays = 3, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 3, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 2, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 4, NetWorkingDays = 22, AbsentDays = 1, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 5, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 4, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 6, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 6, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 7, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 4, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 8, NetWorkingDays = 21, AbsentDays = 3, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 9, NetWorkingDays = 20, AbsentDays = 8, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 10, NetWorkingDays = 25, AbsentDays = 9, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 11, NetWorkingDays = 24, AbsentDays = 4, Person = Person },
    new PayrollInfo() { Monthof2015 = 12, NetWorkingDays = 26, AbsentDays = 1, Person = Person },
};


PayrollInfoList.Where(p => p.AbsentDays > 6).Select(p => p.Person.Boss.Name).Distinct().Dump();
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you add something like foreign key to 'parent' in each entity?

```
public class PayrollInfo
{
    public int Monthof2015 { get; set; }
    public int NetWorkingDays { get; set; }
    public int AbsentDays { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

And when you can set the new property while creating `Person` - parameter in constructor:

```
public Person(IList<PayrollInfo> list)
{
    this.PayInfo = list;
    foreach(var pay in this.PayInfo)
        pay.Person = this;
}
```

Or just define a method that sets `PayInfo`. Whatever you like.
And then do the same for Person and Boss. 
And then you could write smth like

```
AllPayrollInfos.Where(x => x.Days > 6).GroupBy(x => x.Person.Boss).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```